# Describe the following set

Tags: linear-algebra

We are supposed to describe the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with a proof.

$A_n = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y-x^{2n} \geq 0 \}$

I get that the set contains all functions where $y\geq x^{2n}$ but I'm having trouble seeing the big picture here. 
When my teacher asks us to describe sets the answers have so far been things like the xy-plane, or the 1st quadrant, or all parabolas in the form of $ax^2 + bx + c$. Stuff like that. I can't find a connection like that for this.

It's due tomorrow, so help is appreciated!

Edit: Accidentally put less than instead of greater than at first :(

Comment: I think it's the entire $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ plane except the points that lie above $y=x^{2}$, for $-1 \le x \le 1$. Think of the case of $n=1$: which points does it allow in the set. Then think of $n=2$: what new points does it introduce? Plotting will help.

Comment: Oh my bad, I accidentally did less than instead of greater than. Sorry, I've been doing math all day and my brain is fried.

Comment: Well, in that case, the line of thought is similar. Now it should be all points above $y = x^{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, as well all points for which $-1\le x \le 1$ and $y \ge 0$. Plotting would still help to get the idea and then proceed with a proof.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be easier to figure out what the complement is first. Notice that it's equal to $\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\ y<x^{2n} \right\}$. Look at which (x,y) pairs belong to this set in cases when $|x|>1$ and $|x|\le 1$.